# How could I have better asked this question, which was taken as being about legal terminology?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, vote-to-close

I asked [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336418/is-there-a-word-like-inherit-for-when-a-widower-takes-full-ownership-of-the) question, looking for a word like *inherit/inheritance* that applies to a widow(er) as opposed to an heir or a successor. Really, I was just looking for a good word, a word by which I could express myself more clearly, not a technical legal term. But a lot of people thought (and a couple **insisted**) that I was asking about legal terminology, even going so far as to vote to close the question. How could I have asked differently, and is there any way to salvage it now, with the increasingly negative view the community seems to be taking? Should I just delete the question?

Comment: There are only two votes in favour of closure, well, they recommend migration which is not the same as closure. People can have differences of opinions, it is allowed! And your answer attracted five upvotes, and two good answers. Overall, I think the majority had no qualms about the quality of your question. It's fine as it is. (Perhaps a dictionary reference would have warded off the critics, but it's clear you're not asking about meaning.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you, I freaked out a bit over the two votes to close. I didn't catch the part about migrating as opposed to closure. Getting the attention of moderators is alarming, as though my peers thought it was ok, but the school principal is displeased. Thanks.

Comment: No, no, no. The votes are cast by *members*. A mod doesn't need to cast a vote, they can just "shut down" a question single-handedly See this link on how "closing" posts work: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: I was the user who insisted on legal terminology.  Since you ask why you got the response you did,  my main reason for recommending you go to the Legal SE was your quick acceptance of a  term which I think is rarely applicable today -- and which does have a legal meaning.   My suggestions as what to do in future are: (1) as Rathony said, clarify your Q when commenters ask for clarification and (2) wait at least a day before accepting an answer.   You might have gotten more answers If you had not accepted an answer so quickly.  Please don't let this experience sour you on the site.

Answer (score 2):

> How could I have asked differently?

It is always better to edit your question when a user asks you to clarify some points in the question. You commented

> I said shared estate in my question, and complained abut inherit
>   because it seems to suggest that the survivor didn't share the estate
>   before the death.

but you didn't edit your question. It would have been better if you had edited it as follows:

> You use to inherit when the ownership of an estate which was 100%
>   owned by a husband is transferred to his wife after his death, but
>   which verb do you use when the estate was 50% owned by her before his
>   death. Do you still use to inherit? Is there any better verb to use in
>   this case where the widow(er) taking the full ownership from 50% ownership?

It would have been better if you had edited your question to that effect.

> Is there any way to salvage it now, with the increasingly negative
>   view the community seems to be taking?

You can always edit your question and improving a post is encouraged here. Basically, your question reads more like a request for a legal terminology that can be applied to that specific case. But only two users voted to close it for that reason. It requires five close-votes to put your question on hold unless a moderator is involved with a single hammer.  I don't think just two close-votes mean "the increasingly negative view of the community".

> Should I just delete the question?

No. You need not delete your question. Your question received six upvotes and no downvote. It means six users find your question useful. It won't be a bad idea to try asking the question on [Law Beta Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). I would try if I were you.

Comment: *.... and is there any way to salvage it now, with the increasingly negative view the community seems to be taking?...*" **What increasingly negative view?** The post attracted a few hesitant comments from users who sustained that it was a legal question. Please read [Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/47827/janus-bahs-jacquet) The inexperienced OP just had a couple of kittens over nothing serious.